# updating a user input object of a class from a list view

Tags: java, android

Hi i would like to update an object from a class that is displayed in a listview,

this is the error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.example.andrea.timetableapp.ViewtimeTable$1.onItemClick(ViewtimeTable.java:55)

```
ListView  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);
    Activity2.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Classes>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, Activity2.arrayList);
    Log.i("test", " " + Activity2.arrayList.size());
    listView.setAdapter(Activity2.adapter);
    //selected item

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
 {//Line 55 were the error is     showInputBox(arrayList.get(position).ClassName,arrayList.get(position).Teacher,arrayList.get(position).ClassRoom,arrayList.get(position).Time,position);
                                        }});}

    public void showInputBox(String olditem,String oldteacher, String oldroom, String oldtime, final int index ){

    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(ViewtimeTable.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Input Box");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_box);
    TextView txtMessage=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
    txtMessage.setText("Update item");
    txtMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff2222"));
    final EditText editText=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtinput);
    final EditText editTextteacher=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtinputeditTeacher);
    final EditText editTextroom=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtinputEditroom);
    final EditText editTexttime=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtinputedittime);
    editText.setText(olditem);
    editTextteacher.setText(oldteacher);
    editTextroom.setText(oldroom);
    editTexttime.setText(oldtime);
        final Classes classes2 = new Classes(editText.getText().toString(), editTextteacher.getText().toString(), editTextroom.getText().toString(), editTexttime.getText().toString());

    Button bt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btdone);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           arrayList.set(index,classes2);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: where are you calling the `showInputBox` method from. please update the question with that

Comment: the method is delacred  after calling it  from the same activity

Comment: what is the output of `arrayList.get(position)`

Comment: the output is an instance of a class classes

package com.example.andrea.timetableapp;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by andre on 11/05/2016.
 */
public class Classes implements Serializable {
    String ClassName;
    String Teacher;
    String ClassRoom;
    String Time ;

Comment: i know but something is null in that so want you to check the output and tell what are the values.

Comment: Classname : test 1 
teacher : test2
room : test
time :test

Comment: arrayList is probably null, please check if you are filling the array.

Comment: i dont know what could be null, because everthing is filled up

Comment: need to see the whole class to figure it out. please update code

Comment: i think i solved it ..

i was calling an empty array list , instead of the array list that was being populated from the other class

Comment: so will you answer your own question or should i do it ?

Comment: No i didnt solve it i though i did  i am updating the question now

Comment: i am so sorry i cant update ,due to spam from my network ,thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: welcome, good luck :)